# Call an external function app with http trigger from site script

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, site-design, site-script

I can see you can trigger flows and logic apps from site scripts. I want to call an function app directly without a flow and logic app is that possible? I can see there is a verb called triggerFlow but looking for an approach to send the url of the newly created site to my function app:

https://laurakokkarinen.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-sharepoint-site-designs-and-site-scripts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling Azure Functions directly from a site script is not possible. The only workaround is to trigger a Flow or a Logic app first.

If you are already using Azure Functions, perhaps, it might be easier to create an SPFx extension with a button that will run your Azure function directly. This way you won't need need a premium Power Automate or Logic App license to act as a proxy.